# Twig Template for a Custom Block Plugin

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I'd like to have a custom twig template for custom block plugins from my custom module.

My custom block HeaderText contains

```
public function build() {
    return array(
        '#title' => 'Test',
        '#color' => $this->configuration['color'],
        );
}
```

It is located in myplugin/src/Plugin/Block/HeaderText.php

I have a template block--HeaderText.html.twig located in myplugin/templates which only contains test code

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1><p>{{ color }}</p>
```

However the template isn't used. Following a guide I also added the following to myplugin/myplugin.module

```
function myplugin_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array('myplugin' =>
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'title' => 'Default title',
                'color' => null
                ), 
                'template' => 'block--HeaderText'
            )
        );
}
```

Which did not work either. And even if the previous code did work, I have multiple plugins within that module and that code seems to apply to every block which I don't want to do. I'd like each block to have a unique template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue I ran into was I did not specify '#theme' in the Block Plugin.

I added

```
public function build() {
    return array(
        '#theme' => 'myplugin',
        '#title' => 'Test',
        '#color' => $this->configuration['color'],
        );
}
```

and it worked