# Group entitiy queries for a specific content type using Taxonomy Term

Tags: entities, database

Using Drupal 8 entity query I'm trying to figure how I can fetch values from a specific content type and group them that are associated via a specific taxonomy term.

As seen in the screenshot below I have an entity field called `Group Schedule` that is currently binded to a Taxonomy Term. Is there way I could group those entities that are assigned to a specific taxonomy?

```
Group Schedule Name (field_group_sched)
First Schedule (field_created_date)
Second Schedule (field_created_date)

Group Schedule Name 2 (field_group_sched)
First Schedule (field_created_date)
Second Schedule (field_created_date)
```

[image]

So far I've managed to fetch the values from the `Schedule` Content type

```
// Entity Query for Schedule Node Type
$scheduleType = $query->get('node')
    ->condition('status', 1, '=')
    ->condition('type', 'schedule')
    ->condition('field_associated_programs', $nid_degree, '=')
    ->sort('created')
    ->execute();

foreach ($scheduleType as $key => $program) {

    $programNode = _nodeLoad($program);

    $variables['schedule_content'][$key]['schedule_group'] = $programNode->get('field_group_sched')->value;
    $variables['schedule_content'][$key]['schedule_name'] = $programNode->get('field_schedule_name')->value;
    $variables['schedule_content'][$key]['schedule_date'] = $programNode->get('field_created_date')->value;


}
```

---

```
{% for program in schedule_content %}

<div class="scheduled-dates">
    <h3 class="label">{{ program['schedule_group'] }}</h3>
    <span data-label="{{ program['schedule_name'] }}"  class="date" >{{ program['schedule_date'] }}</span>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you explain more on how you would like to group them please? 
aka for is this for form values or for info display ? 
also why are you using custom code? as can do this with views in like 1 min then make a block and throw it where you need it ?

Comment: I'm trying to group them by using the `Group Schedule` field as shown in the screenshot. Lets say I have to two nodes that are associated with a specific taxonomy. I want to group those two nodes and output them on the twig using custom code.

Comment: Sweet your almost there, were is this on a node display or custom controller or a custom block or on a taxonomy term page ?

Comment: The first block of code is basically the `entity query` that is created on the `.theme` file. The second block of code is the markup on how I can display the output on the twig file

Comment: ok give me a sec i have never tried to do this in a .theme file , usually this kind of stuff is done in a custom module in a controller or block ect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok well here we go if i understand you correct you want nodes linked by a entity reff field value:
in your example "field_group_sched" the see the below condition
but later you can just group stuff by anything you want

```
   // this is the known term id. 
    $group_term_id = 1;
    // for Entity ref use field_name.target_id
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1, '=')
      ->condition('type', 'schedule')
      ->condition('field_group_sched.target_id', $group_term_id, '=')
      ->sort('created');

    $entity_ids = $query->execute();
    if (count($entity_ids) != 0) {
      $entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('node')
        ->loadMultiple($entity_ids);
      // dump($entities); // requires var dummper
      if (count($entities) != 0) {
        $group1 = [];
        $group2 = [];
        // then you can play with order or whatever you want here. 
        foreach ($entities as $node) {
          // These are the loaded nodes;
          $title = $node->getTitle();
          $field_name  = $node->field_schedule_name->value;
          // if the schedule_name is "beer" put in to group 1
          if ($field_name == 'beer') {
            $group1[] = $node;
          }
          else {
            $group2[]= $node;
          }
        }
        // SEND your Nodes to the template here. 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for making the effort in answering my question. By the way how I do render them on the twig file, sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Best Advice is, Make a module look in to drupal console as it can really really really help, as this sort of thing should not live in a theme.
but -> 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module or - 

https://ws.agency/blog/how-create-custom-blocks-d8-and-set-display-twig | https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206290/twig-template-for-a-custom-block-plugin

Comment: Thanks though, I'm still new to drupal so might as well make do with what I have at the moment.

Comment: If new to drupal then for future please watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhEQWfAQpfU so next time you will see you can do this in drupal back end with out needing custom code